# Zero initialize multidimentional array in class constructor C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, constructor, initialization

Is there a way (with C++11) to zero-initialize a *multidimensional* array in a class constructor?

Does this initialize the whole array to zero or just the first dimension?

```
class Example
{
public:
    int array[100][100];

    Example():array{}
    {
    };
};
```

Lastly, will this work with enumerated types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Value-initialization for an array will value-initialize each element in the array. You have an array of arrays, so each element (an array) will be value-initialized. From there, return to the first sentence of this answer for what happens to each array.

The answer to your second question, regular enumerations are scalars, and as such are value-initialized, just like your `int` values in your array, which is to say they're *zero-initialized*. That *may* be problematic if you have an enum without a 0-value representation:

```
#include <iostream>

enum EnumStuff
{
    one = 1,
    two = 2,
    three = 3
};

int main()
{
    EnumStuff arr[10][10]{};
    for (auto const&x : arr)
    {
        for (auto y : x)
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(y) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

There is no 0-value in `EnumStuff`. Just something to keep in mind. A `switch` looking for *only* those three values, for example, will be sorely-disappointed (and shortly thereafter, likely you with it).

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Value initialization (i.e. with `{}`) for multidimensional arrays value-initializes all elements, so all 10000 elements will have value 0.

Comment: Yup, they'll be 0 as well.